# Change the value of a cell in Excel based on cell color

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following VBA code to change the value of cells based on their color but it changes all selected cells including colored cells. Please help me in this regard:-

```
Sub ChangeValueBasedOnCellColor()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Selection.Cells
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each rg In xRg
        With rg
            Select Case .Interior.Color
                Case Is = 16777215
                    .Value = "OFF"

            End Select
        End With
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

Comment: For me, it only changes cells that **aren't** coloured to have the word "OFF" in them.

Comment: 16777215..is color index .if that will match then it should be put the word off in that cells. But in my case in every selected cells it puts off.

Comment: Place a `MsgBox rg.Address & "|" & rg.Interior.Color` statement directly after your `For Each rg In xRg` and then try running the code on a small selection which includes some cells you expect to change and some that you expect to stay the same.  See what values of `Interior.Color` are displayed for each cell.

Comment: Okk... I will try.

Comment: if you want to check for cells with no color then use `If rg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone`

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that both a cell with no/unset/default<sup>*</sup> background colour and a cell with a background colour explicitly set to white have the *same* `.Interior.Color` property value (`16777215`).

To distinguish the two, you need to check each cell's `.Interior.ColorIndex` property instead. A cell with no background colour has `.Interior.ColorIndex` equal to `xlNone` (`-4142`) whilst a cell with a set white background colour has `.Interior.ColorIndex` equal to `2`.

Thus, your code needs to be changed to the following to correctly set the value of the "white" coloured cells to `OFF`:

```
Sub ChangeValueBasedOnCellColor()
  Dim rg As Range
  Dim xRg As Range
  Set xRg = Selection.Cells
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For Each rg In xRg
    With rg
      Select Case .Interior.ColorIndex
        Case Is = 2
          .Value = "OFF"
      End Select
    End With
  Next
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```

**Note:**

<sup>*</sup> If your default background colour is not white, the `.Interior.Color` property value is ***still*** white. This is because the only way to "change" the default cell colour is by adding a coloured background image. The underlying cell's background colour remains unset.